# detect usb on windows 7 using script and transfer files

Tags: batch-file

I tried few scripts and not to my knowledge i can understand why its unable to detect my usb drives.
I am trying to detect an usb drive and just want to transfer files from pc to usb . Any light on this would be really helpful. I get the command C;D;I and D drive is my usb drive and I have folder called smrithi on it  I want to transfer all files to drive D from C:/desktop/*.*   to /smrithi folder on usb.
BUt i get

```
device found :c
Device Found : d
Device Found :I
```

this was my script :

```
@echo off
   setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion


for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  if exist %%d:\custom\ (
     ECHO Device Found : %%d
  )
)
```

Comment: If it finds those three drives then all three of them have a `custom` folder in the root directory.  The code will always use the last matching drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion

rem To only search for a predefined set of volumes (see VOL X: command output)
    set "filterVolumes=F111-0001 A0C1-C34C 0000-0000"

rem To search for all volumes
    rem set "filterVolumes=:"

    set "myDrive="

    for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
        if not defined myDrive vol %%a: 2>nul | findstr /i /l "%filterVolumes%" > nul && ( 
            if exist "%%a:\smrithi\" set "myDrive=%%a:"
        )
    )

    if defined myDrive (
        echo drive found [%myDrive%]
        rem xcopy "%userprofile%\desktop" "%myDrive%\smrithi" /e
    ) else (
        echo USB drive has not been found
    )

    endlocal
```

This uses the `vol` command to see if the drive is available. If it is, the existence of the required folder is tested to determine if it is the searched drive.

To test if the drive is the required one, output of `vol` command is analyzed to see the id of volume. If it match against a predefined list of valid values, the drive is considered. If not, it is discarded. If the `filterVolumes` variable contains `:`, all volumes are considered.

Comment: what if they have a smrithi folder on the root of the c: or d: drives?

Comment: @MattWilliamson, better this way? I did it some time ago for a similar usage with USB units but finally removed it just to avoid maintaining the list of volumes. Anyway this should work.

Comment: Its working fine but I am having a doubt if someone deletes the folder smrithi how can i create folder on usb and then xcopy those files to the folder agaion

Comment: @MC ND Yes, with the caveat of having to maintain the list. Would get a bit tedious with all of the usb drives I have ;) Can you pop in a usb stick and run my code and tell me what you get?

Comment: @smrithi, well, if someone deletes the folder, as it is being used to determine if the drive is the correct one, ... it will not be the correct one and the drive will not be found. If this is a possible scenario, adapt the code to only test for volume number. When drive is found, test if folder exist and if not, create it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
Setlocal 
for /f %%d in (
  'wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=2 and access=0" get name^|find ":"'
  ) DO (
    If exist "%%d\smrithi\" (
       Echo folder found. 
    ) ELSE (
       Echo Folder not found. 
    )
)
```

Comment: I get an error like no instances available but the usb drive is there

Comment: Hmm. What do you get if you just type `wmic logicaldisk get deviceid,drivetype,access` from a command line? Update your answer with the output.

Comment: Tested your code. It works nicely if you belong to the administrators group. If not, wmic will return  a `No instances available` message directly to console.

Comment: @MC ND Ahh, that's why it didn't work for him. In that case, your code is better. Thanks for testing it.